# problems getting the mp3 duration and show an image and a text

Tags: android, textview, imageview, media-player, lag

I'm trying to display an image and a text at a certain time of reproduction of an mp3, but when i start the player and want to show the image along with text for each image, the  mp3 plays correctly from a URL,  and text is displayed, but the images (found locally in the application) has a lag two seconds with respect to its rightful text, I am performing this task as follows;

```
public class WCourse extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener{

//mp3 player
private ImageButton buttonPlayPause;
private Button buttonTaketest;
private SeekBar seekBarProgress;
public EditText editTextSongURL;
public TextView subtitles;

//intent get the course title
public static TextView TextViewTopTitle;

//Slider
public int currentimageindex=0;
Timer timer;
    TimerTask task;
ImageView slidingimage;

//images ids
private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {
        R.drawable.c5_d1, R.drawable.c5_d2, R.drawable.c5_d3, R.drawable.c5_d4, R.drawable.c5_d5,
        R.drawable.c5_d6, R.drawable.c5_d7, R.drawable.c5_d8, R.drawable.c5_d9, R.drawable.c5_d10,
        R.drawable.c5_d11, R.drawable.c5_d12, R.drawable.c5_d13, R.drawable.c5_d14, R.drawable.c5_d15,
        R.drawable.c5_d16, R.drawable.c5_d17, R.drawable.c5_d18, R.drawable.c5_d19, R.drawable.c5_d20,
        R.drawable.c5_d21, R.drawable.c5_d22, R.drawable.c5_d23, R.drawable.c5_d24, R.drawable.c5_d25,
        R.drawable.c5_d26, R.drawable.c5_d27, R.drawable.c5_d28, R.drawable.c5_d29, R.drawable.c5_d30,
        R.drawable.c5_d31, R.drawable.c5_d32, R.drawable.c5_d33, R.drawable.c5_d34, R.drawable.c5_d35,
        R.drawable.c5_d36, R.drawable.c5_d37, R.drawable.c5_d38, R.drawable.c5_d39, R.drawable.c5_d40,
        R.drawable.c5_d41, R.drawable.c5_d42, R.drawable.c5_d43, R.drawable.c5_d44, R.drawable.c5_d45,
        R.drawable.c5_d46
    };      
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds; // this value contains the song duration in milliseconds. Look at getDuration() method in MediaPlayer class

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.watch_course);        
    //intent
    TextViewTopTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    TextViewTopTitle.setText(bundle.getString("RESULT2")+" ");
    getText(bundle.getString("RESULT2"));        
    subtitles = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subs);
    // handler of slider
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();    
    initView();          
    // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AnimateandSlideShow();              
        }
    };                      
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {         
         mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    }
}, 0, 500); }



// Helper method to start the animation on the splash screen
         public void AnimateandSlideShow() {                
    //abc = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);
    int abc = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    if(abc > 0 && abc < 18000 ){
        currentimageindex=0;
        //slidingimage.getAnimation();
        subtitles.setText(this.getString(R.string.t1));
    }
    if(abc >= 18001 && abc < 26000){
        currentimageindex=1;
        subtitles.setText(this.getString(R.string.t2));
    }
    if(abc >= 24000 && abc < 32000){
        currentimageindex=2;
        subtitles.setText(this.getString(R.string.t3));
    }
    if(abc >= 30000 && abc < 37000){            
        currentimageindex=3;
        subtitles.setText(this.getString(R.string.t4));
    }
    if(abc >= 35000 && abc < 41000){
        currentimageindex=4;
        subtitles.setText(this.getString(R.string.t5));
    }
    if(abc >= 39000 && abc < 46000){
        currentimageindex=5;
        subtitles.setText(this.getString(R.string.t6));
    }
    if(abc >= 44000 && abc < 50000){
        currentimageindex=6;
        subtitles.setText(this.getString(R.string.t7));
    }            
}   
private void initView() {

    buttonTaketest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.taketest);
    buttonTaketest.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonPlayPause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause);
    buttonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);

    seekBarProgress = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBarTestPlay);  
    seekBarProgress.setMax(99); // It means 100% .0-99
    seekBarProgress.setOnTouchListener(this);
    editTextSongURL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextSongURL);
    editTextSongURL.setText(R.string.c5);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}

/** Method which updates the SeekBar primary progress by current song playing position*/
private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
    seekBarProgress.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds)*100)); // This math construction give a percentage of "was playing"/"song length"
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause){

        //ImageButton onClick event handler. Method which start/pause mediaplayer playing 
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(editTextSongURL.getText().toString()); // setup song from http:// URL to mediaplayer data source
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); //  call this method after setup the datasource in setDataSource method. After calling prepare() the instance of MediaPlayer starts load data from URL to internal buffer.

            /**slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
            slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]); // setup song from http:// URL to mediaplayer data source
            currentimageindex++;
            slidingimage.getAnimation();*/                                  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL                 
        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.start();
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);                              
        }
        else {
            mediaPlayer.pause();                
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
            //slidingimage.wait();

            //button on pause
        }           
        /**if(!slidingimage.isShown()){
            slidingimage.getAnimation();
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause); //button on playing


        }else {
            slidingimage.clearAnimation();              
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play); //button on pause
        }*/

        primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
    }
    if(v.getId() == R.id.taketest){
        //Go to WebView
        Intent i = new Intent("com.mariposatraining.courses.WebViewTest");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.SeekBarTestPlay){
        // Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer to seekBar primary progress position
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
            int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100) * sb.getProgress();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
     // MediaPlayer onCompletion event handler. Method which calls then song playing is complete
    buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    // Method which updates the SeekBar secondary progress by current song loading from URL position
    seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
}   

//get Course Text
    private void getText(String string) {


    Button backButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.back2);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {           
        finish();         
      }       
    });    
}   

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {           
        super.onStop();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        currentimageindex=0;    
        finish();

    }}
```

which actually try to compensate for the times shown to display images, but does not work! any idea to solve the problem of time lag of two seconds?

Comment: Try not to use the UI thread for that purpose. Try using Asynctask or something like that..I recommend asynctask as it has a lifecycle method called onpostexecute and doinbackground which may come handy for you check this link http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html hope it helps

Comment: Hi Nav, thanks for read, i'm trying to find out because I have a two-seconds delay, and after that a possible solution,

Comment: yeah what ever resource is taking time to load put that in doinbackground and once done it will itself call the onpostexecute where you can write your logic...hope you got the hint ;)

Comment: surprising still, as the text and images are scheduled to appear at the same time, why this does not happen like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i solved this, with this code, maybe is not perfect, but is a solution for my app:

```
slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);
        int abc = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        if(abc >= 0 && abc == 0 ){
            currentimageindex=0; //46 Test Value - Real Value 0
        }
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && abc > 1 && abc < 90100 ){
            currentimageindex=0;
            //slidingimage.getAnimation();
            subtitles.setText(this.getString(R.string.t1));
```

Very simple yep..
Hope this help others...